# Does the antd select component give a secondary confirmation prompt when the value changes?

Tags: ant-design-vue

When some important data is changed, such as the value of the selectA component is modified, the value of the component B will change, and there is a linkage relationship. Now, when the value of the selectA component changes, a second confirmation prompt box needs to be given, and click the prompt box the OK button, the value of selectA changes, otherwise it does not change.

I looked at the api of the select component and didn't find the hook before the value changed, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make the select a controlled component that will only change if you change its value. E.g:

```
state = {
    select: ""
}

handleChange = value => {
    setSelect(value)  // If you don't write this, the value of select will not change.
}

<Select value={select} onChange={handleChange} />
```